# Registering xml schema in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, schema, xsd, xmltype

How to register xml schema which depends on the some other schemas.

ex

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="xml.xsd"/>
```

The above line is in my schema , there are other imports as well. How to mention that while registering a schema in oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one simple solution for this, it is to simply specify the `schema url` which you used while `registering` the schema in the oracle, as the attribute value for `schemaLocation`